# WinUI xaml binding crash

Tags: winui-3

This is for an existing Win32 project I'm trying to convert to WinUI. For new projects, this works correctly.

In a new Window I have the content dialog:

```
    <ContentDialog x:Name="W2M_Message1" PrimaryButtonStyle="{ThemeResource AccentButtonStyle}" IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="True" PrimaryButtonText="">
        <InfoBar MinHeight="100" Name="W2M1_Q" IsOpen="True"  Severity="Informational"  Title="{x:Bind s1}"  IsIconVisible="True"  IsClosable="False"  Message=""  />
    </ContentDialog>
```

The idl/h/ expose the "s1" normally.
And then it compiles, but crashes at this point:

```
void XamlBindings::Initialize()
{
    if (!_pBindings->IsInitialized())
    { 
        _pBindings->Update();
    }
}
```

with the _pBindings has an invalid pointer value 0xddddddddddddd.

This happens after I call my Window::Activate().

If I don't put the bind, it works correctly, but then I 'd need to do everything manually.

What *could* be wrong? In a new project, this call occurs at the same place (after I call Activate()) and the pointer is valid.

Comment: *"invalid pointer value 0xddddddddddddd which I'd say its uninitialized pointer."* - Uninitialized data is filled with the `0xCD` pattern in the debug heap. The `0xDD` pattern is used for [freed blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-debug-heap-details#find-buffer-overruns-with-debug-heap). This is a lifetime issue.

Comment: A common way to introduce lifetime issues is by passing (`const`) references into coroutines. What's the signature of `s1`?

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal sample? [`x:Bind` supports better debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension), you can debug `x:Bind` in your project.

Comment: As [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) says, *{x:Bind} bindings support debugging by enabling you to set breakpoints in the code files that are generated as the partial class for your page. These files can be found in your obj folder, with names like (for C#) `<view name>.g.cs`*. @MichaelChourdakis, is there any update about the question?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT not yet, yes I have been placing breakpoints but to no avail. Basically, I'm working on it and will provide feedback soon I hope.